# sas if no observations then stop execute

Tags: if-statement, sas

Any idea why this stop execution code doesn't work?
There is no observation in table1, but proc print still runs.

```
%macro execute (inputdata=work.table1);

data _null_;
if 0 then set &inputdata. nobs=n;
call symputx('totobs',n);
stop;
run;


%if &totobs. = 0 %then %put exit;
%else %do;
%put execute further;
%end;
%mend execute;
%execute(inputdata=work.table1)

proc print data= work.table1;
run;
```

Comment: You don't have any code that would stop the PROC PRINT from running. Of course if there aren't any observations why do you care since PROC PRINT will not generate any output if there is no input.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Proc PRINT` occurs after the macro execution, and thus there is nothing preventing the proc from being submitted.  The `%put exit` only causes a message from the macro system to be displayed in the log window.

There are some tricky things you could do, but shouldn't

- definitely not this: have the macro emit source code `;*` when there are no observations.  The semi-colon asterik (`;*`) will cause a null statement (or complete an open one), and then start a [comment statement](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=n1v51exifva71an1cvfn2z6j26lo.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) in the source code (being handled by the submit processor) that ends at the next semi-colon. 
   `%if &totobs. = 0 %then %str(;*);` 
  When totobs is zero the submit processor will see source code
   
  `;*proc print data= work.table1;`
- maybe this: halt all further execution of the currently submitted source code.  Inside the macro an `%abort cancel` will do this.
  `%if &totobs. = 0 %then %abort cancel;`

The best answer is the question "What do you want to happen?"

Comment: ```%if &totobs. = 0 %then %abort cancel;```
This code works like gold!